# Scheduling jobs using dropwizard-sundial

Tags: java, job-scheduling

I am trying to use dropwizard-sundial and am having trouble with a resource. I'm not sure if it's a classpath issue or if I am failing to register resources properly.

This is my application class' run method:

```
public void run(DataLoaderApplicationConfiguration configuration, Environment environment) throws Exception {
    logger.info("Started DataLoader Application");
    final String template = configuration.getTemplate();
    environment.healthChecks().register("TemplateHealth", new TemplateHealthCheck(template));
    // JOBS
    environment.jersey().packages("com.tradier.dataloader.jobs");
}
```

I get the following error at runtime:

```
INFO  [2015-04-07 15:00:19,737] com.xeiam.sundial.plugins.AnnotationJobTriggerPlugin: Loading annotated jobs from com.tradier.dataloader.jobs.

[WARNING] 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:293)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected problem: No resource for com/tradier/dataloader/jobs
at org.quartz.classloading.CascadingClassLoadHelper.getJobClasses(CascadingClassLoadHelper.java:217)
at com.xeiam.sundial.plugins.AnnotationJobTriggerPlugin.start(AnnotationJobTriggerPlugin.java:72)
at org.quartz.QuartzScheduler.startPlugins(QuartzScheduler.java:1102)
at org.quartz.QuartzScheduler.start(QuartzScheduler.java:211)
at com.xeiam.sundial.SundialJobScheduler.startScheduler(SundialJobScheduler.java:102)
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out a working example at https://github.com/timmolter/XDropWizard. It uses annotated jobs. You need to add the package name conatining the annotated jobs in your config.yaml file like this:

```
sundial:
  thread-pool-size: 5
  shutdown-on-unload: true
  wait-on-shutdown: false
  start-delay-seconds: 0
  start-scheduler-on-load: true
  global-lock-on-load: false
  annotated-jobs-package-name: org.knowm.xdropwizard.jobs
```

If you still are getting an exception, leave a report at: https://github.com/timmolter/dropwizard-sundial/issues.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a classpath issue.
From https://github.com/timmolter/Sundial/blob/develop/src/main/java/com/xeiam/sundial/SundialJobScheduler.java#L102:

```
public static void startScheduler(int threadPoolSize, String annotatedJobsPackageName) {

try {
  createScheduler(threadPoolSize, annotatedJobsPackageName);
  getScheduler().start(); // ---> Line 102
} catch (SchedulerException e) {
  logger.error("COULD NOT START SUNDIAL SCHEDULER!!!", e);
  throw new SchedulerStartupException(e);
}
```

I'm also using Sundial in my dropwizard project, I have all my jobs defined in jobs.xml, Sundial config defined in the .yaml file, and start it as follows:

```
     SundialJobScheduler.startScheduler();
     SundialManager sm = new SundialManager(config.getSundialConfiguration(),environment); 
     environment.lifecycle().manage(sm);
```

Comment: Thanks Rahul. I have my project set to use jobs.xml and that works fine. However if I try the other option of using annotated jobs, the CascadingCLassLoadHelper does not recognize the resource(my directory containing the jobs classes). Curious to see if that option worked for you or if its a bug.

Comment: Do you mean defining a job with annotations? Or just starting a job that's already defined in jobs.xml? I haven't tried either yet, all my jobs are in the xml file and start according to their cron schedule. Will try and update

Comment: Yes, I meant defining a job with annotations and including that folder in config.yaml file. If i do that, the classes in the folder are not loaded and I get an exception. The jobs.xml file option works fine, but I am having trouble with the annotation option. If you happen to try it I'd appreciate your experience. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

@Jeyashree Narayanan, the jobs package should not be configured in the application class as you have shown, it can be easily done in the yml file. Here is the explanation in simple steps:

Step 1: Configuration in yml file and the Configuration class

```
sundial:
  thread-pool-size: 10
  shutdown-on-unload: true
  start-delay-seconds: 0
  start-scheduler-on-load: true
  global-lock-on-load: false
  annotated-jobs-package-name: com.tradier.dataloader.jobs
  tasks: [startjob, stopjob]
```

Configuration Class:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class DropwizardSundialConfiguration extends Configuration {

    @Valid
    @NotNull
    public SundialConfiguration sundialConfiguration = new SundialConfiguration();

    @JsonProperty("sundial")
    public SundialConfiguration getSundialConfiguration() {
        return sundialConfiguration;
    }
}
```

Step 2: Add and configure the dropwizard-sundial bundle in the application class.

```
public class DropwizardSundialApplication extends Application<DropwizardSundialConfiguration> {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DropwizardSundialApplication.class);

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  new DropwizardSundialApplication().run("server", args[0]);
 }

    @Override
    public void initialize(Bootstrap<DropwizardSundialConfiguration> b) {
  b.addBundle(new SundialBundle<DropwizardSundialConfiguration>() {

   @Override
   public SundialConfiguration getSundialConfiguration(DropwizardSundialConfiguration configuration) {
    return configuration.getSundialConfiguration();
   }
  });
 }
}
```

Step 3: Add the required job classes.
Here is a sample Cron job class:

```
@CronTrigger(cron = "0 19 13 * * ?")
public class CronJob extends Job {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CronJob.class);
    @Override
    public void doRun() throws JobInterruptException {
        logger.info("Hello from Cron Job");
    }
}
```

I have also written a blog post and a working application which is available on GitHub with these steps. Please check: http://softwaredevelopercentral.blogspot.com/2019/05/dropwizard-sundial-scheduler-tutorial.html